# yii2 How can I get the textInput value and copy to variable php

Tags: php, view, yii2, bootstrap-modal, onchange

I am new for Yii2 and I have a question.

In my _form.php  I have one field (`textInput`)

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'Test')->textInput() ?>
```

I want to get `Test` (`textInput`) value (`onchange`) and store value to variable PHP $var.

example:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'Test')->textInput([, 'onchange' => $var]]) ?>


<?php
        Modal::begin([
            'headerOptions' => ['id' => 'modalHeader'],
            'id' => 'modal',
            'size' => 'modal-lg',
            'toggleButton' => [
            'label' => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></i>'.' '.Yii::t('app','Teste'),
            'class' => 'btn btn-success',
            ],
        ]);
        echo "<div id='modalContent'>";
            echo $this->render('/controller/modal',['var' => $var]);
        echo "</div>";
        Modal::end();
    ?>
```

Comment: If you just want to save the textinput value to a variable we can achieve that through controller.is that okay ?

Comment: onchange work client side  .. so explain better what do you mean with get the value and store to php variable  .. (client side you have not php ).. explian your needs .

Comment: Has to be done inside the view, event type ,onchange

Comment: What I need is to get values contained in fields textinput to pass as a call parameter of a Modal. example :

Answer (score 1):

**problem resolution :**

1) use javascript onclick event and / or onchange;

2) use ajax to send client x server;

3) use session to store the necessary information